# not lint equal sign using the lintr package

Tags: r, lintr, vscode-r

I have the following configuration in my `~/.lintr` file

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(
     assignment_linter = NULL
)
```

But I am getting this:

[image]

Any idea of what I could change to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this post](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/967#issuecomment-1030070967), it seems DCF files are finicky about indentation, and line ends:

```
linters: with_defaults(
  assignment_linter = NULL
  )
```

Comment: oh wow thanks! I had no idea what type of file that is, but now its working;)